# Generic arithmetic in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

I am trying to implement a generic routine to compute the square of the Euclidean distance between two vectors. This compiles on nightly.

1. Is this the Rustacean way to do this?
2. Will this generic code be fast as the monomorphic code for T=f32?

```
#![feature(zero_one)]
#![feature(iter_arith)]
use std::ops::{Add, Sub, Mul};
use std::num::Zero;

pub fn distance2<T>(x: &[T], y: &[T]) -> T
    where T: Copy + Add<Output = T> + Mul<Output = T> + Sub<Output = T> + Zero
{
    x.iter().zip(y.iter())
        .map(|(xi, yi)| { let d = *xi - *yi; d * d })
        .sum()
}
```

Comment: There are [quite a few duplicates of this](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[rust]+cannot+move+out+of+borrowed+content). In such cases as these, please do search for the error messages—there answers will often already be on Stack Overflow.

Comment: As for the second matter, generic code is monomorphised as part of compilation, so it’s equivalent.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan I'm missing what this has to do with "moving out of borrowed content" — the code compiles without any error. This seems to be a request for code review, which would be better suited at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ (with the caveat it should fit the requirements there).

Comment: @Shepmaster: [the code was changed](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/31395094/revisions) six minutes after I closed it, changing the effect of the question completely.

Comment: user72961: please don’t do things like that, especially not after it’s been closed; create a new question instead. And as @Shepmaster says, codereview.stackexchange.com is a better fit for that sort of a question.

Comment: Wouldn't re-opening be more appropriate than asking a new question?